# How to check if button clicked, IF form is actually submitted Selenium / TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to java/selenium/testNG, I have an issue were I run 4 sets of data using the dataprovider, however, One set of data is incorrect just for the purpose of testing that the test works. I first check the button is displayed then clicked. I want to be able to check that the button was clicked and then check if the form was submitted IF the form was not submitted then print error. I am unsure on how to do this my code is below:

```
WebElement  login = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label"));


      //If statement - will check if element is Displayed before clicking on login button.
      if(login.isDisplayed()){
          login.click();
          //Main Event is logged If Passed
          Reporter.log("Login Form Submitted  | ");
          logger1.info("Submit Button Clicked");
      }else{  

          Reporter.log("Login Failed  | ");
          Assert.fail("Login Failed - Check Data | ");
          //Main Event Log Fail  
         }  




    WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"));

    if(logout.isDisplayed()){
        logout.click();
    Reporter.log("Logout Successful  | ");
    }else {
        Reporter.log("Logout Failed");
        Assert.fail("Logout Failed - Check Data | ");
    }
```

The test displays a error message as "logout Failed" but it should display the first message "Login Failed" How do I get it to check if login and form was submitted successfully?

The reason it prints the second message is the code runs passed that point and selenium cant see the logout button displayed.

Any thoughts on were I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static By outButton = By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label");
if(driver.findElements(outButton).size() > 0)
{
    logout.click();
    Reporter.log("Logout Successful  | ");
}
```

Comment: Sorry not sure that is correct. I want to check that the web element is displayed. If it is then the element is clicked and the form is submitted, however, I want it at that point to also check that the form was submitted and if the form failed or not.

Comment: Reporter.log("Login Failed  | ");
          Assert.fail("Login Failed - Check Data | ");  Isnt displayed if the login fails due to incorrect data

Answer (score 0):

after submitting the form, you should make the webdriver wait for some condition to be true.

something like that

```
int timeout = 30
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
wait.until(new Function <WebDriver, Boolean>(){
    //@Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {                    
            //if the login has been successful return true
            //if not, return false
        }               
    });
```